# Firefox running on Antergos copy paste not working

Tags: x11, firefox, clipboard, antergos

Ordered a ssd drive finally. so done a wipe down and installed as normal. everything work, can copy paste in every app except firefox. have googled and in the past there  was an issue but no one is currently having this problem. it was a straight install nothing else modded or changed yet. right click copy then paste does nothing, same as keyboard shortcuts.

firefox version 53.0.2-1

Any ideas

Comment: Are any of the working applications also GTK3? What version of GTK3 is installed?

Comment: gtk 3.22.13-1 is installed

Comment: just seems odd. i just wiped an uptodate antergos with ff. now there is no copy paste. i did do another reformat but same issue

Comment: (`gtk3-demo` → Text View → Hypertext → Run) attempt copy-paste in the resulting window.  Does it work there?

Comment: Also, which kind of copy-paste is broken?  Menu-entry/keyboard-shortcut clipboard copy-paste, or the middle click selection paste?  Or both?

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a bug introduced by the gtk3-3.22.13-1 package (or possibly one of the packages updated alongside it). [Here's the bug report.](https://bugs.archlinux.org/index.php?do=details&task_id=54000&action=details.add_notification&ids=54000&user_id=18587)

EDIT: Fixed by upgrading to gtk3-3.22.14-1